# Simultaneous diagonalization of Cartan generators of $SO(6)$

Tags: group-theory, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

This question is naive but for some reason I'm not getting the expected result.

The generators of $SO(6)$ can be written in this way:

$$(J_{ab})_{cd}=i(\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}-\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}),\qquad a,b,c,d=1,...,6\tag{1}$$

The commuting generators are

$$H_k=J_{2k-1\,2k},\qquad k=1,2,3\tag{2}$$

Thus, in this case, $H_1=J_{12},\,H_2=J_{34}$ and $H_3=J_{56}$ are the Cartan generators. These are not diagonal but can be simultaneously diagonalized to have the usual ones

$$H_1^D=E_{11}-E_{22}$$
$$H_2^D=E_{33}-E_{44}\tag{3}$$
$$H_3^D=E_{55}-E_{66}$$

So,

$$H^D_k=SH_kS^{-1}\tag{4}$$

In this particular case, or in general, which matrix should do the work?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [Georgi's Lie algebras in particle physics](http://93.174.95.29/_ads/D5D3D9B7B99967877D17B66D48160D92), page 237:

The Cartan generators can be written in this way

$$H_1=-i J_{12}=\sigma_2\oplus I_2\oplus I_2,$$

$$H_2=-i J_{34}=I_2\oplus\sigma_2\oplus I_2,\tag{1}$$

$$H_3=-i J_{56}=I_2\oplus I_2\oplus\sigma_2,$$

eigenvectors of $\sigma_2$ are

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i\\ 
i & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
\pm i
\end{pmatrix}=\pm \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
\pm i
\end{pmatrix}.\tag{2}$$

So we can construct a simultaneous base for the $H_i$'s:

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
i\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-i\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
1\\
i\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
1\\
-i\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
i\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
-i\\
\end{pmatrix}\right\}.\tag{3}$$

As suggested [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix), we can construct $P$ like this

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 &  &  &  & \\ 
i & -1 &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  & 1 & 1 &  & \\ 
 &  & i & -i &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  & 1 & 1\\ 
 &  &  &  & i & -i
\end{pmatrix},\tag{4}$$

so

$$H_i^d=PH_iP^{-1}.\tag{5}$$